# Mapping local JSON file to Realm object using Object Mapper

Tags: json, swift, realm, objectmapper

I have local JSON file and i am trying to map that json to realm object using ObjectMapper_Realm library.

```
var totalLessonArray = [Lesson]()
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json") {

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                totalLessonArray = Mapper<Lesson>().mapArray(JSONArray: jsonResult as! [[String : Any]])

            } catch {
                 // handle error
            }
        }
```

When i print totalLessonArray i get following error in my 4 level deep list

```
//...
quizScore = 0;
            quizQuestions = List<Question> <0x6000022e4d80> (
                [0] Question {
                    question = What are the synonym of sympathy? Drag and drop in the box below.;
                    answer = <Maximum depth exceeded>;
                }
            );
//...
```

This is the model file

```
class Lesson : Object, Mappable{
    @objc dynamic var lessonNumber : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var totalChapter : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var completedChapter : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var quizTaken : Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var isFinished : Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var isCurrentlyWatchingLesson : Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var currentlyWatchingChapter : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var lessonTitle : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var quizScore : Int = 0

    var chapter = List<Chapter>()
    var quizQuestions = List<Question>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
      self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        lessonNumber <- map["lessonNumber"]
        totalChapter <- map["totalChapter"]
        completedChapter <- map["completedChapter"]
        quizTaken <- map["quizTaken"]
        isFinished <- map["isFinished"]
        isCurrentlyWatchingLesson <- map["isCurrentlyWatchingLesson"]
        currentlyWatchingChapter <- map["currentlyWatchingChapter"]
        lessonTitle <- map["lessonTitle"]
        quizScore <- map["quizScore"]
        chapter <- (map["chapter"], ListTransform<Chapter>())
        quizQuestions <- (map["quizQuestions"], ListTransform<Question>())
    }

}
```

I have json which is 4-5 level down deep. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `Codable` struct?

Comment: @Adrian i am not familiar with Codable.. i think its the problem of realm.
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4326
Is there any fix for this?